# Problems accurately timing the loading of a image from file into UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to measure the time taken to load a large photo (JPEG) from file into an UIImageView on iOS 8.0.

My current code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func loadImage(sender: UIButton) {
        if let imageFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("large_photo", ofType: "jpg") {
            // start our timer
            let tick = Tick()
            // loads a very large image file into imageView
            // the test photo used is a 4608 × 3456 pixel JPEG
            // using contentsOfFile: to prevent caching while testing timer
            imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFile)
            // stop our timer and print execution time
            tick.tock()
        }
    }
}

class Tick {
    let tickTime : NSDate
    init () {
        tickTime = NSDate()
    }
    func tock () {
        let tockTime = NSDate()
        let executionTime = tockTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(tickTime)
        println("[execution time]: \(executionTime)")
    }
}
```

When I load a very large image (4608 x 3456 JPEG) on my test device (5th gen iPod touch), I can see that the execution time is ~2-3 seconds and blocks the main thread.  This is observable by the fact that the UIButton remains in a highlighted state for this period of time and no other UI elements allow interaction.

I would therefore expect my timing function to report a time of ~2-3 seconds.  However, it reports a time of milliseconds - eg:

```
[execution time]: 0.0116159915924072
```

This `tick.tock()` prints the message to the Console *before* the image is loaded.  This confuses me, as the main thread appears blocked *until after* the image is loaded.

This leads me to ask the following questions:

- if the image is being loaded asynchronously in the background, then
  why is user interaction/main thread blocked?
- if the image is being loaded on the main thread, why does the
  `tick.tock()` function print to the console *before* the image is
  displayed?

Comment: I think UIImage lazy loads the image data. Try using NSData to load the image in memory and check the byteCount (in case NSData lazy loads) and then create the UIImage from that NSData.

Comment: Also I bet UIImage reads the image file using a different thread.

Comment: Hi Tobias.  I will try this out and get back to you.  If the UIImage is lazy loading and using a different thread - that would explain the fast 'execution time', but doesn't explain why the main thread appears to be blocked .. ?

Comment: The main thread might be blocking to wait on the image data. It sees their is an image assigned so it waits for the image data to be loaded. This is totally a guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to what you are measuring here:

Loading the image from disk:

`UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFile)`

And decompressing the image from a JPEG to a bitmap to be displayed:

`imageView.image = ....`

The first part involves actually retrieving the compressed JPEG data from the disk (disk I/O) and creating a `UIImage` object. The UIImage object holds a reference to the *compressed* data, until it needs to be displayed. Only at the moment that it's ready to be rendered to the screen does it decompress the image into a bitmap to display (on the main thread).

My guess is that your timer is only catching the disk load part, and the decompression is happening on the next runloop. The decompression of an image that size is likely to take a while, probably the lions share of the time.

If you want to explicitly measure how long the decompression takes, you'll need to do it manually, by drawing the image to an off screen context, like so:

```
let tick = Tick()

// Load the image from disk
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFile)

// Decompress the image into a bitmap
var newImage:UIImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, 0);
image.drawInRect(CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:image.size.width, height:image.size.height))
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

tick.tock()
```

Here we are replicating the decompression that would happen when you assigned the `image` to the `imageView.image`

A handy trick to keep the UI responsive when dealing with images this size is to kick the whole process onto a background thread. This works well because once you have manually decompressed the image, UIKit detects this and doesn't repeat the process.

```
// Switch to background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT.value), 0)) {

    // Load the image from disk
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFile)

    // Ref to the decompressed image
    var newImage:UIImage;

    // Decompress the image into a bitmap
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, 0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:image.size.width, height:image.size.height))
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Switch back to main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Display the decompressed image
        imageView.image = newImage
    }
}
```

A disclaimer: The code here has not been fully tested in Xcode, but it's 99% correct if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to time this using a unit test, since the XCTest framework provides some good performance measurement tools. I think this approach would get around the lazy loading issues... although I'm not 100% on it.

```
func testImagePerformance() {
    let date = NSDate()

    measureBlock() {
        if let imageFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("large_photo", ofType: "jpg") {
            imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFile)
        }
    }
}
```

(Just an aside, you mentioned that the loading blocks the main app thread... you should look into using an NSOperationQueue to make sure that doesn't happen... you probably already know that: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/)

Comment: Hi Zac, just tried unit testing using `measureBlock() {...}`.  It reports similar execution times to my `tick.tock()` measurements.  And yes :)  I am aware how to run code on other threads to keep UI responsive - this is more trying to learn what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Shoot. I had expected the unit tests to trap any background threads. Sorry about that... only other thing I can think of – are there any delegate methods that will notify you when loading/rendering is done? It would be very "un-Apple" to do something in the background and not provide some kind of callback or notification...